# …unwanted transparent text (Xelatex)

Tags: xetex, transparent

I need transparent pictures behind a text. I have a working minimal example, however the text now also appears transparent and I can't find the error. Can someone give me a hint where the problem is?

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}


\begin{document} 


text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[opacity=0.5,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)
   {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Pic.JPG}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

"move the code for the picture before the text" That's It. Thanks a lot.

Comment: unrelated but never use either of these packages with xelatex or lualatex `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: When you say "the text appears transparent", do you mean that you cannot see it, or that  its intensity is reduced, because it is covered with a transparent image?

Comment: move the code for the picture before the text.

Comment: A comment to show a graphic result and clarify the discussion.

The text is over the image as expected. The figure occupies the full physical page, and it behaves as a background image. I used the figure `example-grid-100x100pt.jpg`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqC4L.jpg